# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory from multiple xml files

Tags: python

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

XS = '{http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_view}'

mols = {'CID_11249995','CID_11249995'}

molstring = str(mols);

tree = ET.fromstring(open('C:/Python27/xml/'+ molstring +'.xml','r'))

root = tree.getroot( )

print(root)
```

This gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "C:\Users\HENRY\Desktop\prac1.py", line 6, in      tree =
>   ET.fromstring(open('C:/Python27/xml/'+ molstring +'.xml','r'))
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   "C:/Python27/xml/set(['CID_11249995', 'CID_11249995']).xml"

Comment: Are the entries in `mols` meant to be different filenames?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: which file you try to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For reading the data from multiple xml files**

```
mols = {'CID_11249995' , 'CID_11249995'}

for mol in mols:

     tree = ET.parse('tree path' + mol + '.xml')

     root = tree.getroot( )   

     print(root)
```